# Error: Extra }, or forgotten \right in split equation

Tags: equations, align

I am getting an error in this equation. There is a missing ] at the end.

```
\documentclass[5p,preprint,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left
|B_{\mathrm{d}}\right|&=\frac{B_{\mathrm{r}}}{\pi}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{l w}{2 d \sqrt{4 d^{2}+l^{2}+w^{2}}}\right)
\right.
\\
\left.&-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{l w}{2\left(t_{\mathrm{m}}+d\right) \sqrt{4\left(t_{\mathrm{m}}+d\right)^{2}+l^{2}+w^{2}}}\right)
\right] 
\end{split}
\end{equation}



\end{document}

\endinput
```

Comment: A left/right construction cannot span a line break knot the issue here) or span cells, which is the problem here, move `\left. ` to the other side of `&`. Note that most of the left/right constructions in this example is irrelevant

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! In the  2nd line, replace `\left.&` with `&\left.`. A `&`  cannot separate a pair of \left ... \right.

Answer (score 2):

I have delete the old package `times`

```
\usepackage{times}
```

and I have changed with `newtxtext`. After I have used to not have the errors of compilations `\Biggl`and `\Biggr` when the formula has a split.

[image]

```
\documentclass[5p,preprint,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\bigl|B_{\mathrm{d}}\bigr|&=\frac{B_{\mathrm{r}}}{\pi}\Biggl[\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{l w}{2 d \sqrt{4 d^{2}+l^{2}+w^{2}}}\right)\\
&-\tan ^{-1}\Biggl(\frac{l w}{2\left(t_{\mathrm{m}}+d\right)\sqrt{4\left(t_{\mathrm{m}}+d\right)^{2}+l^{2}+w^{2}}}\Biggr)
\Biggr]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much

Comment: @soooleh Did you have doubts that it didn't work? 